# cygwin opens three windows instead of one

Tags: terminal, cygwin

If I open a cygwin terminal window it opens three instead of one window.

The titles are

> C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe
>   Cygwin Terminal
>   `<my host and current directory>`

Only the third window is usable, into the others I can't input anything, but when I close one of the three windows the other both are closed also.

After rebooting windows(Win7x64), it's random.
Sometimes only one window will be opened, even when I start multiple terminals for each terminal only one window is opened.
But sometimes after rebooting I always open three windows.

If I use `taskkill /f /im conhost.exe` after starting a terminal then the other windows are closed but the terminal window stays open.
But that shouldn't be the solution, as I get annoying behaviour, each command opens a new window which disappears when the command finished.
The conhost process was introduced in windows 7 by microsoft for correct handling drag&drop functionality with terminal windows.

Anybody who knows this effect? And how to solve it?

[image: window 1]
[image]
[image: window 3]

Comment: give what's in your shortcut. mine has `C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -`

Comment: My short cut is is the same

Comment: how about you take a screenshot of the 3 windows and include it here. And you look in task manager and show a "command line" column and look at what the command like column has for them. And why does conhost.exe come into it?

Comment: I somehow got Cygwin into this messed up state.  My solution was to kill all Cygwin related processes and double check the mintty.exe command line arguments.

Comment: This happens to me when opening an X session (Xfce, I didn't try other desktops). It opens one or two instances on the taskbar, but only the second one works. It looks random, no ideia how to solve it.

Answer (score 5):

Had the same issue after moving to Windows 10. Solved it running mintty in Windows 8 compatibility mode. 
This is discussed here:
https://github.com/mintty/mintty/issues/439

Answer (score 1):

Try to run your shell (bash) in mintty without profile processing.

If you are using proper mintty (you may check that it must be complied/linked for Windows GUI subsystem) the two standard console windows are created by some other software. At least I can recall some wrapper allowing to run standard console applications (cmd.exe) inside cygwin console.

At last, run ProcessMonitor and check what process are created during mintty startup.

Answer (score 0):

Find mintty in cygwin/bin. Open properties "General Tab" at the bottom next to "Attributes" check the box labeled √"Hidden". Apply and then click OK.

At the top of your file explorer. Click "View" & check the box next to √"Hidden items".

Because windows 10..

Comment: (1) The question is about Cygwin on Windows 7.   (2) Can you explain what this does?